# Geocode certain types of addresses ie all pharmacies within a specific area

Tags: r, geocode, ggmap

I am new to R and have learned how to geocode a specific address, but I would like to know if it is possible to geocode all pharmacies within a certain area without providing addresses.  To start, I tried to geocode Walgreens within a specific zip code where only 1 Walgreens exists.  I tried:

```
test = data.frame(geocode("walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00927", "all"))
```

It returned the location of the walgreens in that zip code.  Then I tried a zip code that has 2 walgreens:

```
test2 = data.frame(geocode("walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00925", "all"))
```

This gives the error:

> Error in data.frame(address_components = list(list(long_name = "Walgreens",  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 5

Eventually, I would like to find x,y coordinates for all pharmacies within Puerto Rico.  Is there a way to have it return multiple x,y coordinates when searching for 'walgreens', 'pharmacy' or other key words?

Comment: `geocode("walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00927", "all")` returns a list. `data.frame(geocode("walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00927", "all"))` returns an error message. The same happened to your second case. I think the key seems to be converting lists to data frames.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried. I hope this will help you. `geocode("walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00927", "all")` returned a list. When you specify `output = "all"` in `geocode()`, R returns a list. So, `data.frame(geocode("walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00927", "all")` should not work.

I tried to extract longitude and latitude from the list. I am not sure what would be an optimal way to get longitude and latitude from the list. Yet, I have done the following and create a data frame in the end. Seeing the output, it seems that `geocode()` picked up Walgreens in the neighbourhood. That is, your search picked up Walgreen shops not only in the post code (i.e., 00925) but also in other post codes.

```
library(ggmap)

### Get geocodes
foo <- geocode(location = "walgreens, san juan, puerto rico, 00927", output = "all")

### Get longitude, latitude, and address from the list

mylist <- lapply(1:length(foo$results), function(x) {

            lat <- foo$results[[x]]$geometry$location$lat
            lon <- foo$results[[x]]$geometry$location$lng
            address <- foo$results[[x]]$formatted_address

            mydata <- cbind(lat, lon, address)
            mydata

})

### Create a data frame.
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, mylist))


#         lat         lon                                                           address
#1 18.4029425 -66.0560009 Walgreens, Ave Universidad, San Juan, San Juan 00927, Puerto Rico
#2  18.397714  -66.004824                                     Walgreens, San Juan, PR 00924
#3  18.370949  -66.067786                                  Walgreens, Rio Piedras, PR 00926
#4  18.369908  -66.058266                                        Walgreens, Cupey, PR 00926
#5  18.376544  -66.046526                                Walgreens, San Juan, PR 00926, USA
```